# Get the extension from a filepath

Tags: powerquery

I need to test the extension of the imported file as to if it is `CSV` or `XLSX`

I am trying

```
FP = Text.AfterDelimiter([Path], ".", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}),
```

```
let 
   FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fp"]}[Content]{0}[TheFilePath],
   FP = Text.AfterDelimiter([FilePath], ".", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}),
   Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FilePath))
in Source
```

But I get the error

```
There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?
```

I did try

```
 FP = Text.AfterDelimiter(_[FilePath], ".", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd})
```

This did not correct the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, which finds the part after the last period?

```
let  FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fp"]}[Content]{0}[TheFilePath],
Extension=List.Last(Text.Split(FilePath,"."))
in Extension
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elegant way I just solved this for paths where some fines have no extension. Hope it helps someone.

= Table.AddColumn(#"AddPathColumn", "Extension", each if Text.Contains([Path], ".") then Text.AfterDelimiter([Path], ".", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}) else "no extension", type text)